# Copy using a common key value in XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Here is my source xml which I am struggling to transform using XSLT 2.0.

The application that I'm working on, support XSLT 3.0.

Any help is appreciated using xslt 2.0 or xslt 3.0. Thanks

`<empID>` is the common key to be used for look-up.

**Source XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MasterFile>
   <Summary>
      <Workers>
         <WorkerSummary>
            <EmpID>83921</EmpID>
            <Name>amitzner</Name>
            <Title>Executive Assistant</Title>
         </WorkerSummary>
         <WorkerSummary>
            <EmpID>65291</EmpID>
            <Name>akapoor</Name>
            <Title>Senior Network Engineer</Title>
         </WorkerSummary>
      </Workers>
   </Summary>
   <Payroll>
      <Employee>
         <Employee_ID>83921</Employee_ID>
         <Payroll_ID>80034</Payroll_ID>
         <OtherIDs>27239</OtherIDs>
         <OtherIDs1>27215</OtherIDs1>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <Employee_ID>65291</Employee_ID>
         <Payroll_ID>85934</Payroll_ID>
         <OtherIDs>23912</OtherIDs>
         <OtherIDs1>29321</OtherIDs1>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <Employee_ID>87196</Employee_ID>
         <Payroll_ID>86089</Payroll_ID>
         <OtherIDs>67896</OtherIDs>
         <OtherIDs1>37891</OtherIDs1>
      </Employee>
   </Payroll>
   <Employees>
      <Employee>
         <empID>83921</empID>
         <LocalJuris>NYCRes</LocalJuris>
         <City>New York</City>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <empID>65291</empID>
         <LocalJuris/>
         <City>Houston</City>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <empID>98218</empID>
         <LocalJuris/>
         <City>Boston</City>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <empID>87196</empID>
         <LocalJuris>NYCRes</LocalJuris>
         <City>Dallas</City>
      </Employee>
   </Employees>
</MasterFile>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterFile>
    <Employees>
        <Employee>
            <empID>83921</empID>
            <LocalJuris>NYCRes</LocalJuris>
            <City>New York</City>
            <Name>amitzner</Name> <!-- This needs to be copied from Summary/Workers -->
            <Title>Executive Assistant</Title> <!-- This needs to be copied from Summary/Workers -->
            <Payroll_ID>80034</Payroll_ID><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
            <OtherIDs>27239</OtherIDs><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
            <OtherIDs1>27215</OtherIDs1><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <empID>65291</empID>
            <LocalJuris/>
            <City>Houston</City>
            <Name>akapoor</Name><!-- This needs to be copied from Summary/Workers -->
            <Title>Senior Network Engineer</Title>  <!-- This needs to be copied from Summary/Workers -->
            <Payroll_ID>85934</Payroll_ID><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
            <OtherIDs>23912</OtherIDs><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
            <OtherIDs1>29321</OtherIDs1><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
        </Employee>
        <Employee> 
            <empID>98218</empID>
            <LocalJuris/>
            <City>Boston</City>
        </Employee>
        <Employee>
            <empID>87196</empID>
            <LocalJuris>NYCRes</LocalJuris>
            <City>Dallas</City>
            <Payroll_ID>86089</Payroll_ID><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
            <OtherIDs>67896</OtherIDs><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
            <OtherIDs1>37891</OtherIDs1><!-- This needs to be copied from Payroll/Employee -->
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
</MasterFile>
```

I'm able to copy some of the nodes but having hard time getting the output that I expect to produce with below XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>         
            
        </xsl:copy>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="LocalJuris">
        
        
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        
        <Name>
            <xsl:for-each select="../../../../MasterFile/Summary/Workers/WorkerSummary">
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </Name>        
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template match="Summary|Payroll">     
             
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried using xsl:key as suggested by Martin Honnen which returns following.

Could anyone please help me figure out what i am missing ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>         
            
        </xsl:copy>
        
    </xsl:template>   
    

    
    <xsl:key name="emp" match="Summary/Workers/WorkerSummary" use="EmpID"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="emp" match="Payroll/Employee" use="Employee_ID"/> 
    
    
    
    <xsl:template match="EmpID">
               
        <xsl:copy select="key('emp', empID)!(Name, Title, Payroll_ID, OtherIDs, OtherIDs1)"/>      
   
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Summary|Payroll">     
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are talking about a "key" and using an "xsl:key" e.g. `<xsl:key name="emp" match="Payroll/Employee" use="Employee_ID"/> <xsl:key name="emp" match="Summary/Workers/WorkerSummary" use="EmpID"/>` and then the `key` function (e.g. `key('emp', empID)!(Name, Title, Payroll_ID, OtherIDs, OtherIDs1)` in the context of  `Employees/Employee` should help. So give that a try.

Comment: Thanks Martin. However, I couldn't make it to work. Can you please help me ? I updated the original question with my new attempted XSL with xsl:key

Answer (score 1):

Use e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:key name="emp" match="Summary/Workers/WorkerSummary" use="EmpID"/>
    
  <xsl:key name="emp" match="Payroll/Employee" use="Employee_ID"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Payroll | Summary"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('emp', empID)!(Name, Title, Payroll_ID, OtherIDs, OtherIDs1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample is at [this link](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Akey%20name%3D%22emp%22%20match%3D%22Summary%2FWorkers%2FWorkerSummary%22%20use%3D%22EmpID%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Akey%20name%3D%22emp%22%20match%3D%22Payroll%2FEmployee%22%20use%3D%22Employee_ID%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Payroll%20%7C%20Summary%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Employee%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22node%28%29%2C%20key%28%27emp%27%2C%20empID%29%21%28Name%2C%20Title%2C%20Payroll_ID%2C%20OtherIDs%2C%20OtherIDs1%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Astrip-space%20elements%3D%22*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3CMasterFile%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3CSummary%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CWorkers%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CWorkerSummary%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpID%3E83921%3C%2FEmpID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CName%3Eamitzner%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTitle%3EExecutive%20Assistant%3C%2FTitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FWorkerSummary%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CWorkerSummary%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmpID%3E65291%3C%2FEmpID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CName%3Eakapoor%3C%2FName%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTitle%3ESenior%20Network%20Engineer%3C%2FTitle%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FWorkerSummary%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FWorkers%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FSummary%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3CPayroll%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee_ID%3E83921%3C%2FEmployee_ID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPayroll_ID%3E80034%3C%2FPayroll_ID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3COtherIDs%3E27239%3C%2FOtherIDs%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3COtherIDs1%3E27215%3C%2FOtherIDs1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee_ID%3E65291%3C%2FEmployee_ID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPayroll_ID%3E85934%3C%2FPayroll_ID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3COtherIDs%3E23912%3C%2FOtherIDs%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3COtherIDs1%3E29321%3C%2FOtherIDs1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee_ID%3E87196%3C%2FEmployee_ID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CPayroll_ID%3E86089%3C%2FPayroll_ID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3COtherIDs%3E67896%3C%2FOtherIDs%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3COtherIDs1%3E37891%3C%2FOtherIDs1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FPayroll%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3CEmployees%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempID%3E83921%3C%2FempID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CLocalJuris%3ENYCRes%3C%2FLocalJuris%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCity%3ENew%20York%3C%2FCity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempID%3E65291%3C%2FempID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CLocalJuris%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCity%3EHouston%3C%2FCity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempID%3E98218%3C%2FempID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CLocalJuris%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCity%3EBoston%3C%2FCity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CempID%3E87196%3C%2FempID%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CLocalJuris%3ENYCRes%3C%2FLocalJuris%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCity%3EDallas%3C%2FCity%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployee%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FEmployees%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FMasterFile%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Just to confirm, identity template in xslt 2.0 can be replaced with on-no-match="shallow-copy". Is that correct? Could you also help me understand what does this line of code do? `<xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('emp', empID)!(Name, Title, Payroll_ID, OtherIDs, OtherIDs1)"/>` I am confused as to what does exclamation mark do. Is there any documentation that i can refer to know these type of operators ?

Comment: @MAT0718, yes, `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` is a declarative XSLT 3 way for the identity template.

Comment: The operator `!` is the XPath 3 map operator, so, yes, it is documented in any XPath 3 tutorial or reference. I used it in preference of `/` as it allows to enforce the order of the elements you want to be processed/output, I wasn't sure, with input coming from two different sources, if the input document order (which `/` would give) would give the intended result.